# Add resizable circle radius on GoogleMaps API for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to make a circle-like-radius area that user can resize and I can get the number of radius of my current location.

================

tl;dr **Edited**

***I want to make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bmf5p500/2/) as an iOS app with swift.***

=================

Right now, I already created map that listening to current location. Using `CLLocationManager`, I am observing its update location and the map will show my location.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

    // Current Location Components
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var didFindMyLocation = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Current Location Delegate
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        // Observer for update location (Moving)
        mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    }

    // Core Location Location Manager Delegate
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if !didFindMyLocation {
            let myLocation: CLLocation = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 18.0)
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

            didFindMyLocation = true
        }
    }
```

Right now I want to make a circle that resizable. Someone already created that in android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960164/android-draw-resizable-circle-on-google-map). The circle/radius could be shrink or expand by gesture, and I can get the radius of that circle from its center like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722122/get-radius-while-resizing-circle?rq=1). This is what I want for my app.

So, what should I use for this radius-circle-resizable? I am really appreciate every answers and ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a polygon/circle as an Overlay.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_circle

For example:

```
let circle = GMSCircle()
circle.radius = 130 // Meters
circle.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
circle.position = CLLOCATION.coordinate // Your CLLocationCoordinate2D  position
circle.strokeWidth = 5;
circle.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
circle.map = mapView; // Add it to the map
```

Do resize it, i would overlay the whole screen with an UIView, and enable an **UIPanGestureRecognizer**

Check out the example here:
[Resizable Centered Circular UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107305/resizable-centered-circular-uiview)

Comment: Could those circle connected with the map? Because I want to get its radius also, just like the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722122/get-radius-while-resizing-circle?rq=1. Thank you!

Comment: Of course - the GMSCircle is an real overlay for Google Maps - but you are unable to you your UIPanGestureRecognizer (as far as i know). So you could create an "hidden" circle overlay to receive pan gestures, and draw it on the "real" circle.

Comment: Ok, I can draw circe on it. But how to create "hidden" circle overlay to receive pan gesture then draw it on the "real" circle? Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: You can overlay your google Maps with "any" UIView. Like an Circle. Just start with creating an "real" circle as GMSCircle - then, when the user "tap" on the GMSCircle you should change it to another Color (to show the user that he can now change the size) -> then add an SubView with an UIView to receive Pan Gestures (so the GMSMap do not receive any touch events, only the circle)  -> when the user pan, just refresh the circle radius on the GMSMap.